# How to install full ubuntu-desktop after installing with the minimal option?

Tags: apt, 19.10, .desktop

I'm investigating what I will need on new computers I will set up. For this purpose I installed Ubuntu with the minimal option in a VM. I found that `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` and `ubuntu-desktop` are installed. Which brings up the question: **How do I install the full desktop and could I revert this action?**

Both meta packages are built from [`ubuntu-meta`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/eoan/ubuntu-meta), so I downloaded it and compared some of the contained files:

```
--- ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-meta-1.440/desktop-minimal-recommends-amd64
+++ ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-meta-1.440/desktop-recommends-amd64
@@ -1,15 +1,20 @@
 acpi-support
+aisleriot
 app-install-data-partner
 apport-gtk
 avahi-autoipd
 avahi-daemon
+baobab
 bluez
 bluez-cups
+branding-ubuntu
 brltty
+cheese
 cups
 cups-bsd
 cups-client
 cups-filters
+deja-dup
 dirmngr
 eog
 evince
@@ -36,16 +41,21 @@
 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
 gnome-accessibility-themes
 gnome-bluetooth
+gnome-calendar
 gnome-disk-utility
 gnome-font-viewer
 gnome-getting-started-docs
 gnome-initial-setup
 gnome-keyring
+gnome-mahjongg
+gnome-mines
 gnome-power-manager
 gnome-screenshot
 gnome-software-plugin-snap
+gnome-sudoku
 gnome-system-monitor
 gnome-terminal
+gnome-todo
 gpg-agent
 gsettings-ubuntu-schemas
 gvfs-fuse
@@ -61,6 +71,14 @@
 libpam-gnome-keyring
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
 libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager
+libreoffice-calc
+libreoffice-gnome
+libreoffice-impress
+libreoffice-math
+libreoffice-ogltrans
+libreoffice-pdfimport
+libreoffice-style-breeze
+libreoffice-writer
 libwmf0.2-7-gtk
 memtest86+
 mousetweaks
@@ -85,14 +103,25 @@
 printer-driver-sag-gdi
 printer-driver-splix
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
+remmina
+rhythmbox
 seahorse
+shotwell
+simple-scan
 snapd
 speech-dispatcher
 system-config-printer
+thunderbird
+thunderbird-gnome-support
+totem
+transmission-gtk
 ubuntu-docs
 ubuntu-report
 ubuntu-software
 ubuntu-wallpapers
+ubuntu-web-launchers
+usb-creator-gtk
+vino
 whoopsie
 xcursor-themes
 xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```

I guess this is the list of packages that differs from minimal to full desktop?

I tried `sudo apt install --install-recommends ubuntu-desktop` but that had no effect.

Answer (score 5):

Okay I got it. You need to remove `ubuntu-desktop-minimal`:

```
$ sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop-minimal 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
After this operation, 100 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 159362 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.440.1) ...
Removing ubuntu-desktop-minimal (1.440) ...
```

Then install `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aisleriot baobab branding-ubuntu cheese deja-dup duplicity gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0
  gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gnome-calendar gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-sudoku gnome-todo gnome-todo-common gnome-video-effects grilo-plugins-0.3-base gstreamer1.0-gtk3 guile-2.2-libs libabw-0.1-1
  libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0 libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5
  libcolamd2 libcurl4 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevent-2.1-6 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfreehand-0.1-1
  libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgc1c2 libgnome-games-support-1-3 libgnome-games-support-common libgnome-todo libgom-1.0-0 libgpgmepp6 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrilo-0.3-0 liblangtag-common
  liblangtag1 liblirc-client0 liblua5.3-0 libmessaging-menu0 libmhash2 libminiupnpc17 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libnatpmp1 libneon27-gnutls libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.14-0
  libpagemaker-0.0-0 libqqwing2v5 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw19 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-tango
  libreoffice-writer librevenge-0.0-0 librhythmbox-core10 librsync2 libsgutils2-2 libsuitesparseconfig5 libtotem0 libvisio-0.1-1 libvncclient1 libwinpr2-2 libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4
  libxmlsec1-nss libyajl2 lp-solve media-player-info python3-bcrypt python3-fasteners python3-future python3-lib2to3 python3-lockfile python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-monotonic
  python3-paramiko python3-uno remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins
  shotwell shotwell-common simple-scan syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support totem totem-common totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-web-launchers uno-libs3 ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk vino
Suggested packages:
  gnome-cards-data gnome-video-effects-frei0r python3-boto python3-cloudfiles python3-swiftclient ncftp lftp tahoe-lafs python3-pip par2 gnome-video-effects-extra grilo-plugins-0.3-extra
  freerdp2-x11 grilo-plugins-0.3 lirc minissdpd natpmpc raptor2-utils rasqal-utils librdf-storage-postgresql librdf-storage-mysql librdf-storage-sqlite librdf-storage-virtuoso redland-utils
  libreoffice-base ocl-icd-libopencl1 | mesa-opencl-icd | beignet-opencl-icd gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-libav libreoffice-evolution libreofficekit-data
  breeze-icon-theme tango-icon-theme fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito libreoffice-java-common default-jre | sun-java6-jre | java6-runtime | jre sg3-utils python-future-doc
  python-lockfile-doc python3-beaker python-mako-doc python3-gssapi remmina-plugin-exec remmina-plugin-nx remmina-plugin-spice remmina-plugin-telepathy remmina-plugin-xdmcp gnome-codec-install
  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist ttf-lyx java5-runtime
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aisleriot baobab branding-ubuntu cheese deja-dup duplicity gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0
  gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gnome-calendar gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-sudoku gnome-todo gnome-todo-common gnome-video-effects grilo-plugins-0.3-base gstreamer1.0-gtk3 guile-2.2-libs libabw-0.1-1
  libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0 libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5
  libcolamd2 libcurl4 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevent-2.1-6 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfreehand-0.1-1
  libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgc1c2 libgnome-games-support-1-3 libgnome-games-support-common libgnome-todo libgom-1.0-0 libgpgmepp6 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrilo-0.3-0 liblangtag-common
  liblangtag1 liblirc-client0 liblua5.3-0 libmessaging-menu0 libmhash2 libminiupnpc17 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libnatpmp1 libneon27-gnutls libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.14-0
  libpagemaker-0.0-0 libqqwing2v5 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw19 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-tango
  libreoffice-writer librevenge-0.0-0 librhythmbox-core10 librsync2 libsgutils2-2 libsuitesparseconfig5 libtotem0 libvisio-0.1-1 libvncclient1 libwinpr2-2 libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4
  libxmlsec1-nss libyajl2 lp-solve media-player-info python3-bcrypt python3-fasteners python3-future python3-lib2to3 python3-lockfile python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-monotonic
  python3-paramiko python3-uno remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins
  shotwell shotwell-common simple-scan syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support totem totem-common totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk
  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-web-launchers uno-libs3 ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk vino
0 upgraded, 147 newly installed, 0 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
Need to get 73,3 MB/174 MB of archives.
After this operation, 663 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

And moving back to minimal by installing `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` and then removing `ubuntu-desktop` also works:

```
$ sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aisleriot baobab branding-ubuntu cheese deja-dup duplicity gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gnome-calendar gnome-mahjongg
  gnome-mines gnome-sudoku gnome-todo gnome-todo-common gnome-video-effects gstreamer1.0-gtk3 guile-2.2-libs libabw-0.1-1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0
  libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2 libcurl4 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libe-book-0.1-1
  libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevent-2.1-6 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfreehand-0.1-1 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgc1c2 libgnome-games-support-1-3
  libgnome-games-support-common libgnome-todo libgpgmepp6 libgpod-common libgpod4 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblirc-client0 libmessaging-menu0 libmhash2 libminiupnpc17 libmspub-0.1-1
  libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libnatpmp1 libneon27-gnutls libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.14-0 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libqqwing2v5 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw19 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze
  libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librevenge-0.0-0 librhythmbox-core10 librsync2 libsgutils2-2 libsuitesparseconfig5 libvisio-0.1-1
  libvncclient1 libwinpr2-2 libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libxmlsec1-nss libyajl2 lp-solve media-player-info python3-bcrypt python3-fasteners python3-future python3-lib2to3
  python3-lockfile python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-monotonic python3-paramiko python3-uno remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins shotwell shotwell-common simple-scan syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support
  transmission-common transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-web-launchers uno-libs3 ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk vino
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
After this operation, 50,2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 174224 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.440.1) ...

$ sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot baobab branding-ubuntu cheese deja-dup duplicity gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gnome-calendar gnome-mahjongg
  gnome-mines gnome-sudoku gnome-todo gnome-todo-common gnome-video-effects gstreamer1.0-gtk3 guile-2.2-libs libabw-0.1-1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0
  libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2 libcurl4 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libe-book-0.1-1
  libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevent-2.1-6 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfreehand-0.1-1 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgc1c2 libgnome-games-support-1-3
  libgnome-games-support-common libgnome-todo libgpgmepp6 libgpod-common libgpod4 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblirc-client0 libmessaging-menu0 libmhash2 libminiupnpc17 libmspub-0.1-1
  libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libnatpmp1 libneon27-gnutls libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.14-0 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libqqwing2v5 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw19 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze
  libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librevenge-0.0-0 librhythmbox-core10 librsync2 libsgutils2-2 libsuitesparseconfig5 libvisio-0.1-1
  libvncclient1 libwinpr2-2 libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libxmlsec1-nss libyajl2 lp-solve media-player-info python3-bcrypt python3-fasteners python3-future python3-lib2to3
  python3-lockfile python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-monotonic python3-paramiko python3-uno remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins shotwell shotwell-common simple-scan syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support
  transmission-common transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-web-launchers uno-libs3 ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk vino
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 136 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
After this operation, 657 MB disk space will be freed.
```